# port forwarding in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, thrift, portforwarding

I'm trying to split legacy system combined from hbase and php module into two separated containers with the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    image: my-legacy-php
    volumes:
      - ~/workspace/php:/workspace/php
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - hbase
  hbase:
    image: dajobe/hbase
    hostname: hbase-docker
    ports:
      - "43590-44000:43590-44000"
      - "8085:8085"
      - "2181:2181"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "16010:16010"
      - "9095:9095"
      - "9090:9091"
      - "16020:16020"
      - "16030:16030"
      - "60000:60000"
    volumes:
      - ~/workspace/hbase-docker/data:/data
```

I'm using a public [hbase-docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/dajobe/hbase/) image which using port 9090 for thrift while my legacy php module expect to connect via port 9091. I've tried to 'map' or 'forward' within the `docker-compose.yml` file "9090:9091" without lack. I also tried the `expose` attribute of docker-compose but it doesn't takes two ports (only one which is exposed to the other containers). How do I make that append?

I want that the listening port 9090 of hbase container will appear as 9091 from the php container (inside)

Comment: Have you tried external_links ?
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: The ports mapping and the `expose` attributes are only effective for the container to host binding. Not for internal links.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is: Building your own image, with `dajobe/hbase` as the base image, but modifying the hbase configs and ports exposed using `EXPOSE` to match your requirements, And then use that image in your compose file.

But this would require you have build and managing the image by yourself.

Comment: I don't mind to build the image, but `EXPOSE` doesn't let you forward/map the port.. I'll still have to use the save 9090

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put both services on the same docker network.

Specifically, add this to your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Then, in each service's config be sure to include:

```
networks:
  - app_net
```

Finally (and you've already done this), be sure that the correct port mapping is included in the config for hbase:

```
ports:
  - "9090:9091"
```